# I installed anaconda and since then I am getting (base) in the terminal, and it has slowed the system down

Tags: terminal, software-installation, installer-anaconda, datascience-anaconda

I know it will go away when I type in

```
conda deactivate
```

but that is not it, I have also seen that my system has slowed down since I installed Anaconda. It was because of this, I have been fiddling with it just to get rid of slowdowns.

I downloaded it using

```
wget http://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

After downloading that I installed it in again by

```
supreetsingh@zeppelin:~/Downloads$ bash ./Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Changed the location of the install to

```
[/home/supreetsingh/anaconda3] >>> /home/supreetsingh/dodge/anaconda3
```

Did this

```
Do you wish the installer to initialize Anaconda3
by running conda init? [yes|no] 
[no] >>> no
```

Conda was installed and the command conda was working.
I updated all the packages

```
supreetsingh@zeppelin:~/Downloads$ conda update --all
```

Did this to initialise conda

```
supreetsingh@zeppelin:~/Downloads$ conda init bash
```

After that, as the instructions asked me to run this command then I did this

```
supreetsingh@zeppelin:~/Downloads$ /home/supreetsingh/dodge/anaconda3/bin/conda shell.bash hook
```

Everything is working fine, I just want to remove the (base) that comes every time when I start the terminal and it is slowing down the terminal. Also would like to know if there is a better way to install Anaconda.

```
 (base)supreetsingh@zeppelin
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do after activating conda

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```