# Why does my shell now have "(base)" as in "(base) user@laptop"?

Tags: shell

Both my shell emulators (konsole on Kubuntu) as well as the virtuals terminals (Alt+F2, etc.) now display the "(base)" in front of the usual "user@laptop".

I presume some recent update or package installation is causing this.

It is quite annoying. Where does that come from and how do I get rid of it again?

EDIT:
So it is `conda` and its coming from the following lines in `.bashrc`

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
!! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/username/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/username/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/username/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Comment: Probably related: [I installed anaconda and since then I am getting (base) in the terminal, and it has slowed the system down](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/598231/i-installed-anaconda-and-since-then-i-am-getting-base-in-the-terminal-and-it)

Comment: Which shell (not shell emulator) are you using?  `bash` `zsh` `sh`....   Also, what is the output of `echo $PS1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may mean that you are using your anaconda base environment.  Anaconda changes your environment a little bit by adding certain libraries and executables to the respective paths.  In particular, if picks up the anaconda version of python and related tools.

You can install and activate/deactivate other anaconda environments, the prompt changes accordingly.

It mostly does not interfere with the rest of the system, but some programs may be affected.

I admit there may be more reasons to have "(base)" in your prompt, just anaconda seems to be the most common.

Comment: Indeed, I installed anaconda one day ago. That's quite invasive behavior tbh. Do you know a tutorial how to fix things?

Comment: Never checked it, but anaconda itself is a bit invasive too, so I consider the prompt useful.  If you want to get out of anaconda use `coda deactivate`, and `conda activate` brings it back again.

Comment: I wonder whether the activation of conda on start up can be deactivated altogether.

Comment: So you have conda activated right after reboot?

Comment: Right! It shows up right after booting, which is quite invasive.

Comment: I suspect you have something like `conda activate` in your `.profile`, or maybe in `.bashrc`.  Do you know if other users also have anaconda activated when logging in? (I don't think so.)   If yes, it must be in one of the corresponding system-wide  files.

Comment: True, it's in my `.bashrc`, see the posting above. However, commenting out those lines disables `conda activate` since now `conda: command not found`

Comment: Now I see that my anaconda also adds certain directories in front of my PATH.  Never checked that.  And my .bashrc has similar lines as yours.  But what happens if you do `conda deactivate` and reboot?  Do you still get back to conda?