# '(base)' appears at the prompt in Linux terminal

Tags: terminal, prompt, installer-anaconda

suddenly I have a "(base)" before the prompt of my terminal:

```
(base) name@computer:~
$
```

my prompt was defined in bashrc as

```
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
```

But after installing conda I have an extra:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/gigiux/src/conda/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/gigiux/src/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/gigiux/src/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/gigiux/src/conda/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

would this cause this? can I simply remove the extra lines?

Thank you

Comment: your prompt is often defined in:  `$PS1` .  What does: `printf "%s\n"  "$PS1"` show ?  And `(base)` probably designates some repository (git? svn?) name (or "tag"?) that appears to be present in this directory. Do not remove anything until you understand the implications of doing so! conda needs those apparently(and again, PS1 should be the thing used to display the prompt, not the lines you showed)

Comment: Rather than removing the added lines, consider not activating the virtual environment by default. See for example [I installed anaconda and since then I am getting (base) in the terminal, and it has slowed the system down](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/598231/i-installed-anaconda-and-since-then-i-am-getting-base-in-the-terminal-and-it)